# How Extracting address Bitcoin to script multi signature

Tags: address, script, multi-signature, public-key, input-script

I want to extract the correct address from a script multi-signature.

I have this real script multi-signature from [this ScriptSig (tx index 1)](https://blockstream.info/tx/82a69be69e0093791ab7d380369ecffba4f1fe0827a8625ede9d89e94776bc21?expand), so this is a readme script for [this address](https://blockstream.info/address/3CD1QW6fjgTwKq3Pj97nty28WZAVkziNom)

```
OP_2 
    03385adff37fd3d0a620ebc4e9866e81dda8ba8616e5ebcae899c7f51899267ae7 
    034c08511718f947d1a3e152195c5e2756588e3e0c2c7730927eb6647af4942107 
    033da9f8938a5b947a723df21b73fbd3985b719249324d2c705acfb97d63a5df9e 
OP_3 OP_CHECKMULTISIG
```

Now from [this resource](https://learnmeabitcoin.com/guide/p2ms) these value **03385adff37fd3d0a620ebc4e9866e81dda8ba8616e5ebcae899c7f51899267ae7**, **034c08511718f947d1a3e152195c5e2756588e3e0c2c7730927eb6647af4942107**, **033da9f8938a5b947a723df21b73fbd3985b719249324d2c705acfb97d63a5df9e** are the public keys, so this value is a pure public key? and for exstract the address form these I can execute the procedure for build bitcoin primitive address ?

or I'm lost some information for this argument?

an example if I suppose this value is a public key 03385adff37fd3d0a620ebc4e9866e81dda8ba8616e5ebcae899c7f51899267ae7

This should be the compressed public key because it starts with "03" if apply the HASH160 I get this address "14r7XjPtqVijLRhY9BkGAtDqVDp4txsK1X"

Is my reasoning right?

### More Information on the why I want to get the address to P2MSH

I don't want to break the privacy of the address 3CD1QW6fjgTwKq3Pj97nty28WZAVkziNom, I'm reading [this article](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/BiVA%3A-Bitcoin-Network-Visualization-%26-Analysis-Oggier-Phetsouvanh/e5b699334b5b007970ff0d50d1083161c69c37dd) and it catalogated the address 3CD1QW6fjgTwKq3Pj97nty28WZAVkziNom how an scam address, but I think this is restrictive affermation, because the address with "3" can to hide more people/address.

I'm only learning and I don't want break the privacy of the people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct address is `3CD1QW6fjgTwKq3Pj97nty28WZAVkziNom`. The individual public keys are only able to access the coins if they act together in a group of at least 2 out of 3. If you derive a regular p2pkh from each individual key, you will end up searching for utxos that likely don't exist.

Also note that each individual public key does not necessarily mean that there are that many individual people involved. Many security conscious companies and people have multisig addresses with each key stored on a separate device/location, requiring multiple signatures from different systems, etc. They may all still be under the control of a single entity.

When cataloging transactions and matching patterns across the network, you should be working with the P2SH address for a multisig address. Breaking it down into its components will produce incorrect results.

Comment: yes, I understand this, but I think if you build a graph oof address for analyzing the suspicious flows, you should be more analyzing the public key and not the address. So my question is aimed at the process of establishing address to a single public key in a P2MS.

Comment: The individual public keys here don't matter (mostly). You should only be graphing the utxo chain, which relies only on the entire redeem script - note that there are other types of redeem scripts as well, not only multisig ones. If you rely on a key following approach, you might not be able to work with all transactions.

Comment: But this is referer to the script no standard but I think if the bitcoin moved to the 3 different public key I must be represented the 3 nodes and not one. This could mislead the algorithms built on the graphs. also because if I am part of a clan investigated for scam, I can use the public key with the simple P2PKH script and this I shouldn't do it very lightly

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really follow what you're trying to do. Feel free to join me in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100674/how-extracting-address-bitcoin-to-script-multi-signature)